# heroku pgbackups:destroy fails w/ "Internal server error"

Tags: heroku

Here's what happened...

pgbackups:capture gave the following:

```
!    must delete a backup before creating a new one
```

...so I tried deleting a past backup:

```
$ heroku pgbackups 
ID    Backup Time          Size   Database
----  -------------------  -----  --------------- 
b003  2012/07/16 11:27.19  2.4MB  SHARED_DATABASE 
b004  2012/08/09 05:27.57  2.5MB  SHARED_DATABASE

$ heroku pgbackups:destroy b003  
!    Internal server error.  
!    Run `heroku status` to check for known platform issues.

$ heroku status
=== Heroku Status 
Development: No known issues at this time. 
Production:  No known issues at this time.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the error was a "rare occurrence" -- according to Heroku Support.

BTW, the following command succeeded:

```
$ heroku pgbackups:capture -a <app_name> --expire
```

Answer (score -1):

Update your heroku gem - that solved the problem for me

```
gem install heroku
```

Comment: I had just updated the gem... heroku-gem/2.32.6 (x86_64-linux) ruby/1.9.2 autoupdate ...before trying to backup.